# Is there a way to pass a Boolean statement to a python function?

Tags: python, function, boolean

I'm trying to create a function that can search for elements in a list for which a changeable statement is true, so I can search for messages with certain properties for a discord bot.

For example:

```
def search_function(inputList, statement):
    outputList = []
    for item in inputList:
        if statement == true:
            outputList.append(item)
    return outputList
```

The statement would be something that could relate to the elements of the list so the function would be used like: `list = search_function(range(0,10), item > 5)` and list would return as `[6, 7, 8, 9]`.

Obviously that's a very basic use for it, it's more for finding discord messages from users with a certain role, but the theory behind the function is the same. It was just so I didn't have to write the search code every time I need it and could just call on it in other functions when needed.

Comment: Maybe you could put the `if` statement inside your function, if you want it called every time the function is called?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin yeah, the function is so I can change the statement each time, one time I could say look for messages from people with a certain role, another time look for messages after a certain time; just would be easier to turn it into a function I can change the statement for each time so the code is nicer looking than having to throw the search loops in everywhere.